# Silverlight Designer not finding custom controls

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-designer

I'm having an issue where silverlight doesn't recognise custom controls or resources.

I include the namespace and intelisense recognises the item, the application builds fine and runs fine however the designer throws the following error.

```
The type 'x' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference 
and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

Usually I'm able to sort out the issue by performing a clean/rebuild of the project. however recently this route has been unable to resolve the issue.

Is this a known issue with the Visual Studio designer? are there any fixes/work arounds out there?

Thanks

EDIT:

I'm using the following declaration:

```
 xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:x.Classes.Converters"
```

and referencing the control using the following:

```
  <converters:ReportTypeImageConverter x:Name="ReportTypeImage"/>
```

Restarted visual studio this morning when I logged in and now its recognising the controls, which means I can use the designer again.

Comment: Can you post the Xaml that has your  xmlns declarations in it. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go to your Project Properties and put some Reference Paths(folders where you .dll are)

[image]

Hope it Helps

Comment: This seems to be the solution, its weird that I have to tell it to look for its own DLL but no problems so far.