# Error while compiling telerik silverlight project for RadGanttView

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, telerik

I recently upgraded to Silverlight 5 and was created silverlight project through 
RadControls Silverlight Application template in VS2010 and I have selcete RadGanttView 
control from the RadCOntrols list ,and tried to compile and run.

Then I started getting:

> Cannot resolve reference assemblies. Please check the reference
>   assemblies. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core,
>   Version=5.0.5.0,  ....   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

The dlls are the latest for Silverlight 5 and installed in a right directory.
If I add normal silverlight application in VS2010,it works fine without following 
references:

- Telerik.Windows.Controls,
- Telerik.Windows.Controls.GanttView,
- Telerik.Windows.Scheduling.Core

Note: I have Installed `Telerik 2013 Q3 Release`

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Have you tried to change the assembly property "Specific Version" to false? (all of them)

Comment: no ,how can i do this

Comment: Right click on the above mentioned assemblies, then Properties, then you are going to see the property "specific version", double click and it goes to false. Let me know if it works, then i can write a proper answer.

Comment: It is already set to false,but i could not compile

Comment: Well, then try to add the reference again from windows or try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785141/silverlight-designer-not-finding-custom-controls/9794807#9794807 . Where the reference path is the original folder from your .dlls (Telerik and Windows)

Comment: I have created  folder named as DLL and put all three dlls into that and added that folder to reference path.I added reference dll for the silverlight project from that folder,but did'nt get work......